# How to catch Cypress request timeout error?

Tags: request, timeout, cypress

Is it possible to handle request timeouts in Cypress? I don't want error to be thrown. Request for example:

```
cy.request('http://re6l.com/')
```

At the moment I suppose that's not possible and I should use another methods for network requests

Comment: What's the behavior that follows a request timing out? Cypress does allow you to disable failing on a non-2XX/3XX status code, but I'm interested in what you plan on doing with a failed network call?

Comment: @agoff I'm testing web page for bag links. Need to test all links on the page, collect all broken links, mark test failed and proceed to another page

Answer (score 1):

To test for all of the bad links on the page, and output all bad links, I'd imagine that adding `failOnStatusCode: false` will get you most of the way there.

```js
let badLinks = [];
cy.get('a') // get all anchor tags
  .each(($a) => {
    const href = $a.attr('href'); // get the href attribute
    cy.request(href, {failOnStatusCode: false})
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.statusCode >= 400) { // check if the call failed
          badLinks.push(href) // add the failed href to the badLinks array
        }
    });
  })
  .log(badLinks); // log the badLinks
```

Comment: You should log like this `then(() => cy.log(badLinks))  // log the badLinks` otherwise closure logs the empty array.

Comment: doesn't work, the test will fail on first timeouted link. Here is the example https://gist.github.com/serge22/e878a0a2bd755615860c8ec4e497e5cb